# Is my docker node application using all available CPUs?

Tags: azure, docker, node.js, azure-web-apps, pm2

I've got a node app built using a standard node-alpine docker image deployed to Azure App Service. The App Service Plan is set to use 2-core VMs (instance type S2). A single node process will only use a single core at a time. Is Azure scaling the number of containers to fill up available resources? Is it configurable? Or should I be running pm2 inside my container to load balance requests?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will be running one instance of the container. You need to increase the number of app service instances to increase this.

Comment: Sure but that just means I'll have 4 CPUs and still 2 processes, right? Half my CPUs will be idle.

Comment: That's correct, that's just the design of app service containers, 1 container per instance, it doesn't care what resources you are using.